# How to search any string regular expression in AWS Log Insights?

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, logging, filtering, amazon-cloudwatch

I have message filter

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter @message ~= 'simple query'
| limit 20
```

What query should I use for searching results with messages:

```
simple query
simple query 1
simple query 2
simple query error
simple query etc...
```

Big thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that you have are the `strcontains` and `like` methods:

**strcontains**:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter strcontains(@message, "simple query")
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

**like**:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /simple query/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Comment: Big thx, it working!